# CROSS compiling DPDK from source

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to cross compile(for ARM64) DPDK from source as instructed here:
https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/cross_build_dpdk_for_arm64.html

But when I run make, I see this:

```
$ make config T=arm64_armv8_linux_gcc
make: Nothing to be done for 'config'.
```

I have the checkout the main branch, and wondering if compiling through "Makefile" is not supported any more and MESON build system has replaced it ?

I am on top commit of master branch:

https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/commit/9d620630ea30386d7fc2ff192656a9051b6dc6b5

DPDK version:
21.02.0-rc0

Toolchain version is:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --version

aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Linaro GCC 7.3-2018.05) 7.3.1 20180425 [linaro-   7.3-2018.05 revision d29120a424ecfbc167ef90065c0eeb7f91977701]
```

Host machine details are:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Please share the answers for what is the DPDK version you are using? what is tool chain and target environments you are using? error logs if any?

Comment: @VipinVarghese, Just edited the question with details.

Comment: you still have not shared DPDK version. hence marking as need clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK has removed the support for Makefile from `20.11`. One has to rely on `meson-ninja` for the same.

Please use the below as guide for your cross build

```
meson arm64-build --cross-file config/arm/arm64_armv8_linux_gcc
ninja -C arm64-build
```

`DPDK LTS 19.11.6` still uses Makefile.

Comment: Ah, Thanks. It make sense. I tried the step you provided with error message, https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7DVvP2TRR8/

Comment: Looks like, I need to update both MESON and Ninja version to avoid those errors.